# Issue Retrieving results from SQL query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My code performs an `SQL` Query as shown below:

```
$query = 'SELECT 
        cl.*,c.id,c.type,c.firstname,c.surname,c.job,c.company,c.directorycompany_id, dc.id, dc.name, es.id, GROUP_CONCAT(dirc.name), GROUP_CONCAT(dirp.name), GROUP_CONCAT(dirs.name) 
        FROM contactlist_contact cl '.
        'INNER JOIN contact c ON cl.contact_id = c.id '.
        'LEFT JOIN directorycompany dc ON dc.id = c.directorycompany_id '.
        'LEFT JOIN expertsection es ON es.id = c.expertsection_id '.
        'LEFT JOIN directorycolumn dirc ON dirc.directorycontact_id = c.id '.
        'LEFT JOIN directoryprogramme dirp ON dirp.directorycontact_id = c.id '.
        'LEFT JOIN directorysupplement dirs ON dirs.directorycontact_id = c.id '.
        'WHERE cl.contactlist_id = '.$contactListId.' ORDER BY dc.surname';

$db->query($query,$t);
```

I attempt to retrieve the contents of the results returned as shown:

```
while($db->next($t))
{
    $contact = new DirectoryContact(0);
    $contact->setId($db->get('c.id',$t));
    $contact->setContactType($db->get('c.type',$t));
    $contact->setFirstname($db->get('c.firstname',$t));
    $contact->setSurname($db->get('c.surname',$t));
    $contact->setJob($db->get('c.job',$t));
    $contact->setCompany($db->get('c.company',$t));
    $contact->setDisplayColumn($db->get('GROUP_CONCAT(dirc.name)', $t));
    $contact->setDisplaySupplement($db->get('GROUP_CONCAT(dirs.name)', $t));
    $contact->setDisplayProgramme($db->get('dirp.name', $t));

    $directoryCompany = new DirectoryCompany(0);
    $directoryCompany->setId($db->get('dc.id',$t));
    $directoryCompany->setName($db->get('dc.name',$t));

    $expertSection = new ExpertSection(0);
    $expertSection->setId($db->get('es.id',$t));

    $contact->setDirectoryCompany($directoryCompany);
    $contact->setExpertSection($expertSection);

    $this->contacts->add($contact);
}
```

For some reason, every time, these lines are returning `false`.

```
$contact->setDisplayColumn($db->get('GROUP_CONCAT(dirc.name)', $t));
$contact->setDisplaySupplement($db->get('GROUP_CONCAT(dirs.name)', $t));
$contact->setDisplayProgramme($db->get('GROUP_CONCAT(dirp.name)', $t));
```

Does anybody know where I am going wrong? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know it it would solve the issue, but maybe you could try with an alias; e.g:

```
$query = 'SELECT cl.*,c.id,c.type,c.firstname,c.surname,c.job,c.company,c.directorycompany_id, dc.id, dc.name, es.id, GROUP_CONCAT(dirc.name) AS gcname, GROUP_CONCAT(dirp.name) AS gpname, GROUP_CONCAT(dirs.name) AS gsname 
FROM contactlist_contact cl '.
'INNER JOIN contact c ON cl.contact_id = c.id '.
'LEFT JOIN directorycompany dc ON dc.id = c.directorycompany_id '.
'LEFT JOIN expertsection es ON es.id = c.expertsection_id '.
'LEFT JOIN directorycolumn dirc ON dirc.directorycontact_id = c.id '.
'LEFT JOIN directoryprogramme dirp ON dirp.directorycontact_id = c.id '.
'LEFT JOIN directorysupplement dirs ON dirs.directorycontact_id = c.id '.
'WHERE cl.contactlist_id = '.$contactListId.' ORDER BY dc.surname';
$db->query($query,$t);
```

And then, instead of:

```
$contact->setDisplayColumn($db->get('GROUP_CONCAT(dirc.name)', $t));
$contact->setDisplaySupplement($db->get('GROUP_CONCAT(dirs.name)', $t));
$contact->setDisplayProgramme($db->get('GROUP_CONCAT(dirp.name)', $t));
```

Do:

```
$contact->setDisplayColumn($db->get('gcname', $t));
$contact->setDisplaySupplement($db->get('gsname', $t));
$contact->setDisplayProgramme($db->get('gpname', $t));
```